# What's the common way to embed the query parameters in the original URL in a HTTP request URL?

Tags: http, httprequest

What is the usual way to embed the query parameters in the original URL in the http request URL, e.g.

```
http://www.portal.mywebsite.com/res_a/res_b?orig=http://myorigin.com/test1/test2?q1=v1&q2=v2
```

How to pass the query parameters `q1=v1&q2=v2` that are meant to be in the original url to this new url request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is called **URL-encoding**.

Regardless of their content, you're supposed to [always](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the individual request parameter name *and* value. Ultimately, your URL should end up looking like this, when using UTF-8 charset during encoding:

```
http://www.portal.mywebsite.com/res_a/res_b?orig=http%3A%2F%2Fmyorigin.com%2Ftest1%2Ftest2%3Fq1%3Dv1%26q2%3Dv2
```

Every self-respected programming language has an API for this job. Based on your question history, you're familiar with Java, so here's a related question with a Java based example in the answer: [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding/). For other languages, just search around using the additional keywords "URL encoding".

Comment: Thanks, is there an open source lightweight C library for this job?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I don't do C so I can't tell off top of head, but here's a link I think is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+url+encoding